# Terminate scipy minimize as soon as function values is below threshold

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have a function of some parameters that will return a probability. How can I set `scipy`'s  `minimize` to terminate as soon as finds some parameters that will return a probability below a certain threshold (even if it is a "large" probability like 0.1 or so)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first answer is: it depends on the underlying solver you use.
Most of the time, SciPy is just wrapping around efficient implementations in other languages (e.g. SLSQP in Fortran).

This is not the case for `trust-constr`, which is implemented in Python, and allows a callback returning `True` to stop the optimization process. See the documentation of [the `callback` argument of `scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) for more details.

For other solvers, the most straightforward way to achieve what you want is by implementing your own exception, similar to what suggested [Andrew Nelson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4272196/andrew-nelson).
You will not be able to get the inner state of the solver, but your Python script can go on, and the function is evaluated only once at each candidate point.

Here is a reproducible example using the Nelder-Mead Simplex Downhill algorithm:

```py
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from numpy import inf


class Trigger(Exception):
    pass


class ObjectiveFunctionWrapper:

    def __init__(self, fun, fun_tol=None):
        self.fun = fun
        self.best_x = None
        self.best_f = inf
        self.fun_tol = fun_tol or -inf
        self.number_of_f_evals = 0

    def __call__(self, x):
        _f = self.fun(x)

        self.number_of_f_evals += 1

        if _f < self.best_f:
            self.best_x, self.best_f = x, _f

        return _f

    def stop(self, *args):
        if self.best_f < self.fun_tol:
            raise Trigger


if __name__ == "__main__":

    def f(x):
        return sum([xi**2 for xi in x])

    fun_tol = 1e-4
    f_wrapped = ObjectiveFunctionWrapper(f, fun_tol)

    try:
        minimize(
            f_wrapped,
            [10] * 5,  # problem dimension is 5, x0 is [1, ..., 1],
            method="Nelder-Mead",
            callback=f_wrapped.stop
        )
    except Trigger:
        print(f"Found f value below tolerance of {fun_tol}\
            in {f_wrapped.number_of_f_evals} f-evals:\
            \nx = {f_wrapped.best_x}\
            \nf(x) = {f_wrapped.best_f}")
    except Exception as e:  # catch other errors
        raise e
```

Output:

```
Found f value below tolerance of 0.0001            in 239 f-evals:            
x = [ 0.00335493  0.00823628 -0.00356564 -0.00126547  0.00158183]            
f(x) = 9.590933918640515e-05
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback argument to minimize. This is a function that is called at each iteration of the minimization. You can use this to check the value of the function and terminate the minimization if it is below the threshold.

Comment: From scipy's documentation it looks like the callback should have as arguments only the current parameter, and then it should return a bool that tells if the condition has been met or not.
Issues I am having:
a) as it is computationally expensive to evaluate the function, I would rather pass the results from the previous iteration and not compute things again
b) if I pay the cost of computing things again the callback still does not halt the function when it is true...
I call ``scipy.optimize.minimize(f,x0,args,callback = my_callback)``

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit messy but I would use something like the following to wrap the objective function:

```
import numpy as np
class fun_tracker:
    def __init__(self, fun, fatol=None):
        self.fatol = fatol or -np.inf
        self.fun = fun
        self.bestx = None
        self.bestval = np.inf
        self.val = None
        
    def __call__(self, x, *args):
        self.val = self.fun(np.asarray(x), *args)
        if self.val < self.bestval:
            self.bestx, self.bestval = x, self.val

        if self.val < self.fatol:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            return self.val
        
def quad(x):
    return np.sum(x**2)
```